# Use await with r2 to wait for the HTTP response before going further

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I need to wait for the response of a HTTP request before further processing, as several requests to the API must be done in a specific sequence (sometimes depending on the output of another one, sometimes not).

I thought that the following code would achieve that, thanks to the `await` keyword (within an `async` function):

```
const r2 = require('r2');

const get = async i => {
    console.log('before ' + i);
    await r2('http://fgeorges.org/');
    console.log('  -- after ' + i);
};

for ( let i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
    get(i);
}
```

But this code, when executed with Node 8.10.0, gets me the following output:

```
before 0
before 1
before 2
before 3
before 4
  -- after 0
  -- after 1
  -- after 2
  -- after 3
  -- after 4
```

Because of `await`, I would rather expect to have couples of `before/after`, `before/after`, etc.

The goal, at the end of the day, is to be able to build a small layer in the app, that provides a function for each of the few API methods, and let the rest of the code be written like this:

```
makeStuff(...);   // ends up invoking a HTTP endpoint
doThis(...);      // ends up invoking a HTTP endpoint
getThat(...);     // ends up invoking a HTTP endpoint
```

I thought `await` could (also) do that: turn an async function to be used as sync.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: You're not using `await` with the `async` function you created; you're ignoring the Promise it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `get()` function is also `async`, it will implicitly return a Promise for each `await` within it. Your code is not paying attention to the returned Promise, however, so that `for` loop zooms right through.

Create *another* `async` function and call it:

```
const getn = async n => {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
    await get(i);
};

getn(5);
```

That will have the effect of creating a chain of Promise instances. The iterations of the loop (after the first) will effectively happen in the `.then()` callbacks of each Promise in the chain.

You can't `await` the call to `getn()` because the call is not in an `async` function, but you can wait for all the `get()` calls to finish by explicitly coding up a `.then()`:

```
getn(5).then(result => ...);
```

Comment: Thank you @Pointy.  I must admit I got lost a bit within the many layers of `async` and `await` in your response...  Besides, if I have to use a callback in the `then` clause, I don't see how this can solve the callback hell then (which I thought was one of the goal).  I clarified my end goal at the end of the question, which was maybe not clear. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges well the only time you're forced to use an explicit `.then()` callback is when your code is outside an `async` function. If you wrap your "main" code in an immediately-invoked anonymous function, which is a common practice anyway, you can make that function `async` and use `await` instead of `.then()`.